# Can a Muslim sell clothes that are worn generally by the common masses to a Muslim customer?

Tags: halal-haram, work, clothing

Prophet commanded not to resemble mushrikeen.

So the question is: can a Muslim sell clothes that are worn generally by the common masses to a Muslim customer?

Comment: The resemblance which is basically and in consensus of scholars prohibited is the one related to religious matters anything else is rather discussed and therefore in worst case frowned upon.

Answer (score -1):

Following is the answer given by The Scholars of the Standing Committee when asked a similar question like yours,

> Everything that will be used in haraam ways or that one thinks are
>   most likely to be used in such ways, it is haraam to make it, import
>   it, sell it and distribute it among the Muslims.

Reference : https://islamqa.info/en/75007